TAMURA Hall Effect Current Sensor [L31S300S05FS]
I am doing electronic design, and in this design I want to use a sensor to measure the current sent from the battery with a disconnected hall effect and the L31S300S05FS model sensor meets the specifications I am looking for. I will use an STM32 processor. STM32's ADC channel supports up to a maximum of 3.3 V.
If I connect the Vref and Vout pins at the output of this sensor directly to the ADC channels, will I have problems?
Do I need to use an opamp?
Please answer in detail.
https://www.mouser.com.tr/datasheet/2/397/TCOA_S_A0010069265_1-2563810.pdf

